# checking if 2 items from a list are in two different lists

Tags: python-3.x

if i have 3 lists as follows:

```
list1=['tiger','cat','lion','hawk']
list2=['rabbit','bird','goat']
merged_list=['tiger','cat','lion','hawk','rabbit','bird','goat']
```

where list1 contains similar animals
and list2 contains similar animals
but list1 and list2 have different animals.
now i want to chose any two items from merged_list , if one of them is from list1 
and the other is from list2 then ill print predator

i need a way like this:

```
if item1 and item2 from the merged_list are in two different lists:  
        print (predator)
```

Comment: What if the items are both in `list1` or `list2`? Example: `item1='tiger` `item2='cat'`, `item1='rabbit` `item2='bird'`

Comment: Can you also please include some expected inputs/outputs?

Comment: If they r in same list then print nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this, checking if a in list1 and b in list2, or if b in list1 and a in list2.

```py
list1 = ['tiger','cat','lion','hawk']
list2 = ['rabbit','bird','goat']
merged_list = ['tiger','cat','lion','hawk','rabbit','bird','goat']

a = input('First animal : ')
b = input('Second animal : ')

if (a in list1 and b in list2) or (a in list2 and b in list1):
    print('predator')
else:
    print('not predator')
```

**Sample Output**

```py
First animal : goat
Second animal : goat
not predator

First animal : tiger
Second animal : bird
predator

First animal : snake
Second animal : bird
not predator
```

Comment: I used this way of course but am looking for a short way

Comment: You can put the comparison that is probably more likely to evaluate to `True` first, as python disregards the second expression in an `or` statement if the first expression evaluates to `True`.